# Why is deleted code being counted for lack of test coverage

Tags: deployment, code-coverage, developer-console

I have some apex classes that are no longer needed.  I removed all of the code from the files and just left the declaration. There does not seem to be a way to delete the code files that I can find but that is a separate issue.

When I look at code coverage in sandbox Developer Console I see things like (0/806), (0,498), etc... for these files. This is bringing by code coverage down significantly such that I can not deploy to production.

How can I get salesforce to count these as 1 or 2 lines/blocks of code instead of hundreds. I have seen posts saying to clear coverage and test data. I have deleted Test History. The instructions usually point to menus and commands that are not in the current version of Salesforce (I never worked with earlier versions).

I am using Sublime Text with Mavens Mate for my IDE.

I need to deploy big fixes that I have made and I am stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you remove the code lines for production or sandbox?

Comment: In some cases sandbox only, but some were commented out the last time I deployed and did not have an issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already pushed them out to production, then you will want to delete them from production if they are no longer in use.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006188&language=en_US

Comment: I had marked some of these xml files as Deleted in sandbox as stated in the link and thought if I put them in the change set they would become deleted there too.

Comment: I'm nervous about connecting to production with mavensmate since if I compile it moves everything to the server.  So do I change the connection to prod only - do I need to pull the prod version of the file down first?

Comment: Connecting Mavensmate, Force.com IDE, etc to prod is a bad idea. You'll have to Run All Tests for *every* compile cycle, which probably means you'll be able to save only once every 30-60 minutes. You will want to delete those files, but make sure you do it all at once. I'd personally use the Ant toolkit to avoid any catastrophic problems. Build a "destructiveChanges.xml", list the objects to delete, and then try deploying all the changes at once.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean? I don't know how to deploy a change set with an xml file - "destructiveChanges.xml".

Comment: Like @sfdcfox suggested, this should get you started on the right path: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Propagating_Destructive_Changes